# How to connect to remote hadoop/hive (url) from python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have a url I use to connect to Hadoop. I'm prompted for a username and password when entering the url, port etc.

Out of curiosity, is it possible to connect to a remote hive database using python with the set up I have ? Any examples of code ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hadoop prompts for a password, or Hive does? Sounds like it's working fine - can you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

No sure this fit your needs, since  I don't have the details of your setup, but it is possible to connect to hive remotely with Python using HiverServer2.

To get more details, you may reference this page.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Overview

Example of python code are provided here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-PythonClientDriver

Hope this help!